# How to add a new script in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, npm-scripts

I want to add a script `dev` in my `package.json`.

I tried adding it manually in a text editor, but when I run:

```
npm run dev
```

I get some errors. Is it possible to add the script from the terminal?

---

**Edit:**

I added:

```
"scripts:" {
  "start": "node app",
  "dev": "nodemon app"
}
```

and I got this error:

> ```
> nodemon app sh: nodemon: command not found
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! code@1.0.0 dev: nodemon app npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the code@1.0.0 dev script.
> ```

Comment: What is inside the app? 
```start: node app``` should work ok if underlying code is ok

Comment: Have you installed nodemon ?

Comment: well, did you...add nodemon?

Comment: just install [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) as dev dependency, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have not installed the package named [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon):

1. In your CLI enter the following command to install the package:

   ```
   npm install nodemon --save-dev
   ```
2. Then run the following command and it will work:

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```